# pass windows credential from IIS to SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I have deployed a couple of reports in SSRS2012, the report uses the user's windows token to do some verification.  When testing the report in VS I successfully read the windows token but when I deploy to SSRS token is empty.

I did configure all data sources to use windows authentication and to impersonate the user.

any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unclear on the specifics here, but I'm thinking the problem is with the authentication method you're using in IIS. 
Check out this other question:

[Why does Windows/Integrated Authentication in IIS not pass user credentials to SSRS and SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439525/why-does-windows-integrated-authentication-in-iis-not-pass-user-credentials-to-s?rq=1)

The versions are a bit different (SSRS 2005) but I think the issues here are the same. I won't get into it too much, because the answer in that link explains it better than I could, but essentially, it works from Visual Studio because your Windows Token is the one making all the requests. When you deploy to IIS, however, without explicitly configuring Windows Authentication and Identity Impersonation, the requests are being executed as the App Pool User, not the user using your web app. I hope this helps!

Comment: You're right that question has already been anwsered what bugs me is that I've configured IIS to use Windows Authentication and Enabled ASP.NET Impersonation but still when I run my report using an account that is different from the Admin's no token is passed. and I get this error: Query Execution failed for dataset 'datasetname'.(rsErrorexecutiongCommand) Domain\username does not have permissions to impersonate user

Comment: I'm taking a guess here, but the issue you're describing sounds like another answer from that same question, the 'Double Hop' issue. Your website is the first use of those credentials, the second use is to get to the SSRS server, and the third use (which fails) is to access your data source using those credentials. You could try saving credentials to your data sources and see if that helps. I realize that might not be an acceptable final solution, but it might help illuminate the issue. @user998824