# ASP.NET Impersonate Error when accessed remotely

Tags: asp.net, impersonation

I have a website which is hosted on IIS on a server in my network. The website uses an app pool that runs under my username. My username is in the admin group in the server.

The Windows Authentication is enabled while the Anonymous Authentication is disabled. In addition, the ASP.NET Impersonation is enabled.

I enabled impersonation in web,config by adding the following line:

```
<identity impersonate="true" />
```

I also enabled windows authentication in web.config by adding the following line:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

The page contains code that opens a connection to database in the Page_Load:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Default"].ConnectionString);

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            if (connection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
```

When I open the page in the browser on the server, the page works perfectly. When I take the same URL and open it from my machine, I get the error below. Please note that Other websites that don't use impersonation work normally when I host them on the same server and access them from my machine.

The error I get is:

> Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Can you show us your connectionstring "Default"? Make sure the username you are using to connect with SQL Server has an access to the server. Indicate also what authentication you are using, you can check it by going to SQL Server Management studio by going to Security->Logins->Right click the user you are using and check the properties.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Windows/Integrated Authentication in IIS not pass user credentials to SSRS and SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439525/why-does-windows-integrated-authentication-in-iis-not-pass-user-credentials-to-s)

Comment: Thanks for your answer: Here's the connection string: <add name="Default" connectionString="Data Source=ServerHostName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=True" />

Comment: The user does have permission on the database. I'm using windows authentication for the DB

Comment: you don't have a username and password to your connection string right?

Comment: No I don't have username and password because I use windows authentication

Comment: Thanks for the link you provided " TGlatzer". This makes the issue crystal clear for me. But still, I don't know how to fix the problem. I have the windows authentication enabled on the IIS and also on web.config and still I get the same error. Is there something "specific" I can do?

Comment: Can you try changing Integrated Security value to 'SSPI', if not works, remove Integrated Security and add Trusted_Connection=Yes

Comment: Thanks "jomsk1e". I tried both but still not working

Comment: I'm not really sure where the problem came from, but this would help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647396.aspx Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be two things:

1. your browser does not use Kerberos, but NTLM. Since the target does neither get a Kerberos ticket nor the user password, it will not be able to authenticate to the database. You could enable that with Kerberos constraint Delegation or if on the same machine - allowing the IIS process to impersonate any user locally.
2. your database is on another host: you will have to use Kerberos constraint Delegation.

And just to add for clarity: if your ADDCs are not publically available (which they'd better not), then you will not be able to authenticate via Kerberos.
NTLM might relax that Problem, but it often has issues with different Browsers - also: don't use NTLM - remove that Provider from IIS - NTLM is dead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't know which option is my case, but it's worth mentioning that the database is on another server but my machine has access to it. If I host the website on my machine's IIS and I remove impersonation, it will work and successfully access the same DB. In general, I don't know what is Kerberos and I don't know how to enable it

Comment: If you don't know Kerberos, you better get some informations about that. "Windows integrated Authentication" IS Kerberos. Make sure you know what you are using!

Comment: I feel I'm new to the impersonation topic and I'm not sure I got the answer correctly. But if I shouldn't use Kerberos nor NTLM, then how to fix this issue?

Comment: Use Kerberos in Intranet and some Gateway in Extranet (WAP + ADFS for example, or TMG). Using HTTPs relaxes NTLM Problems (NTLM is insecure, because of replay attaks).

Comment: It is intranet, maybe I should use Kerberos, but how to enable it. I already enabled Windows Authentication, isn't this enough?

Comment: Hi "TGlatzer", You suggest that I configure both the IIS and web.config to use windows authentication and deny anonymous users. I already did that but I still have the same problem. Is it (a) The problem is something else or (b) I haven't done what you asked correctly?

Comment: You can't fix that on the IIS only. That's Domain config. Ever heard about SPNs? If not - read about how Kerberos works. You are looking for "Kerberos Constrained Delegation" "Delegation of Windows credentials" and "double hop in Kerberos"

Comment: I tried to put the DB on the same server (where the app is hosted) and now it works, but I still need the DB to be in a different server

Comment: If you'd read about Kerberos you'd instantanously understand, why that happened.

Comment: Thanks. I think I now have a better idea about the issue. The impersonation, basically, works on one server (one hop) when I make connection to another server (DB, for example) it is another hop so this causes the problem.