# Passing Credential of windows authenticated users to web client

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webclient

I'm developing an Intranet application using C# and MVC. I have windows authenticated enabled to authenticate my users. One of the requirement is to enable users to download files from a SharePoint server on the same domain. From my local machine it's no problem but when I publish it on a live server again on the same domain I get error `401 unauthorized` My original code was

```
byte[] fileBytes = await client.DownloadDataTaskAsync(fileUri); 
var response = new FileContentResult(fileBytes, "application/octet-stream"); 
return response;
```

Now after reading up I've come across `CredentialCache` so I've changed my code accordingly

```
CredentialCache cc = new CredentialCache();
cc.Add(
    new Uri(fileUri), 
    "NTLM", 
    new NetworkCredential("username", "pass", "domain")
);
client.Credentials = cc;
```

I can't figure out how to get the password and pass it to `NetworkCredential`. So my question is how do I get and pass the **password** to `NetworkCredential` as I don't store it anywhere because the users are windows authenticated.

Comment: depends on how you configured impersonation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7441365/578411

Comment: @rene I haven't enabled `<identity impersonate="true" />`

Comment: If you have not enabled that you don't have the credentials of the caller on the server.

Comment: @rene If I enable it, how will I then get the credentials of the user?

Comment: Is there any role based access on the files or all the authenticated users can access it?

Comment: Most basic is on the [HttpContext.User](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.user(v=vs.110).aspx) but I'm not sure if you can make another security hop once impersonated.

Comment: @SamGhatak All authenticated users can access the files

Comment: @rene `HttpContext.User` will only give me username not password or am I missing something?

Comment: If user level checking is not required for the file access, you can use a specific credential and only use that in `NetworcCredential object`...keeping the credential in web.config/application constants..

Comment: @SamGhatak The thought had crossed my mind but the credentials are changed every few weeks or so and I would rather solve that issue before then setting them forever

Comment: Recently I came across a similar issue with `NetworkCredential` for `FtpWebRequest`....ultimately had to put credential in web.config...need some more experts' advice...

Comment: If you have enabled impersonation the current security context is that of the authenticated user, not the identity of the webserver process. I would suggest you go over [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998351.aspx) to see if that clarifies stuff.

Comment: @rene I've enabled impersonation now I can download the file but upload fails :/